# How do I prevent, or get rid of the <code>Abs^\[Prime]</code> in the output of a partial of a Normalize[vector]? 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, hold, numerical-value, vector-calculus

12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows

How do I prevent, or get rid of the `Abs^[Prime]` in the output of a partial of a Normalize[vector]?

The code below shows the problematic form which uses the builtin Normalize function (xBad, euBad), and a working version (xGood, euGood) which uses handmade normalization.  I want to give the results to Graphics3D, which doesn't evaluate the `Abs^[Prime]`, and gives an error.  How can I tell Mathematica to evaluate this expression, or replace it with something it can evaluate to a number?

```
Module[{xBad, xGood, euBad, euGood}
 , xBad[u_, v_] := 
  Normalize@Cross[{Cos[u], 0, Sin[u]}, {0, Cos[v], Sin[v]}];
 xGood[u_, v_] := Module[{V},
   V = Cross[{Cos[u], 0, Sin[u]}, {0, Cos[v], Sin[v]}];
   V/Sqrt[V.V]
   ];
 euBad[u_, v_] := Module[{U}, D[xBad[U, v], U] /. U -> u];
 euGood[u_, v_] := Module[{U}, D[xGood[U, v], U] /. U -> u];
 Print["Bad: ", euBad[1, 1] // N];
 Print["Good: ", euGood[1, 1] // N];
 ]
```

Output:

```
Bad: {-0.413412+0.645618 (-0.909297 (Abs^\[Prime])[0.540302]+0.265448 (Abs^\[Prime])
[0.841471]),1.00274 +0.645618 (-0.909297 (Abs^\[Prime])[0.540302]+0.265448 (Abs^\[Prime])
[0.841471]),-0.643852-0.414547 (-0.909297 (Abs^\[Prime])[0.540302]+0.265448 (Abs^\[Prime])
[0.841471])}

Good: {-0.829093,0.587059,-0.376946}
```

Comment: Try `ComplexExpand@Normalize@Cross...` --- *Mma* works over the complex numbers by default. `ComplexExpand` will convert `Abs[]` to an expression that works in real analysis.

Comment: Or replace `Abs` (not differentiable) with `RealAbs` (differentiable), `Normalize@Cross[{Cos[u], 0, Sin[u]}, {0, Cos[v], Sin[v]}] /. Abs :> RealAbs`